# Clicking a checkbox to select a row hides the content of the row

Tags: angular, primeng

I've implemented a **PrimeNg** data-table inside a dialog.

**HTML**

```
<p-dataTable #modt [value]="employeesList" [(selection)]="selectedEmp" dataKey="id"
 scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300px" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelected($event)">
    <p-column [style]="{'width':'40px'}" selectionMode="multiple" dataKey="id">
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="fname" header="First Name" [style]="{'width':'20%'}"></p-column>
    <p-column field="lname" header="Last Name" [style]="{'width':'75%'}"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Each time I select a row, then the content of the row disappears. It appears again when I de-select the row (see picture).

[image]

```
onRowSelected(evt: any){
  debugger;    
  console.log("Content of the selected row...", evt.data);
}
```

I'm getting the content of the selected row just fine.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you provide a StackBlitz that reproduces the problem please?

Comment: i made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-close-zujzcb) you can produce your problem here?

Comment: @fatemefazli sorry it took me forever to get back to you as I was trying to setup the Stackblitz, I've never used that before (thanks for the tip). I looked at your example, it was selecting all the rows, so I added **id** to every item, now it's working fine. So, besides the ids, everything is the same. I don't know why it's not working on Visual studio code.

Comment: It looks like css issue because on selecting row, text color will be white and background color will be blue. In your case there is no background color.  Can you please check if data exists in that row after selection using inspect element.

Comment: @NikhilChandu Really? Inspect element shows that at there are data in each `<td></td>`. I can't believe I waste so much time. I guess, I need to apply some color on some `if row is selected`?

Comment: @Richard77 You need to apply background color for ui-state-highlight class
Try this code it give you clear idea.
`.ui-datatable tbody > tr.ui-widget-content.ui-state-highlight {
    background-color: #186ba0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}`

Comment: @NikhilChandu `tr.ui-state-highlight`I did finally the trick. What a waste of weekend? Thank you so so so much.

Comment: Glad you fixed you issue! just as a FYI You should stay away from data-tables. Use primeNG turbotables instead. They are easier to maintain https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

Comment: @patricio Vargas, thank you for the advice. It seems like data-tables are older technologies. This is a legacy code I'm working on.